# N2Cms How to start

Tags: asp.net-mvc, n2, n2cms

I have a static website and I want to use the N2 Cms + Asp.Net Mvc,
I don't know how to start sorting thins up, when should I create a page, and when should I use a part, and what controllers should I make ?

does any one have a blog or a tutorial?
I saw their N2.Template project but it is too complicated,
and lacks the documentation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might also be interested in this PDF that someone on the N2 mailing list created:

http://interferencelogik.com/docs/N2CMS_TheLittleHandbook.pdf

The documentation Dan linked to is a bit sparse and not very well maintained, but the basic concepts haven't changed much recently and they cover them pretty well.

EDIT:
the link provided earlier is no longer working, and here is a new link:

https://n2cmsdocs.atlassian.net/wiki/download/attachments/1245210/N2CMS_TheLittleHandbook.pdf?api=v2

Comment: that is exactly what i mean, their documentation looks obsolete, i searched their site and couldn't find any thing about how to manage Zones for example?

Comment: Document is not available by this link ( Could you please repost new one?